# How to list classList? Angular (unit testing). The class is given by @Input() @HostBinding('class.isBigButton') isBigButton = false;

Tags: angular, unit-testing, fixtures

component:

```
@Input() 
@HostBinding('class.isBigButton') isBigButton = false;
```

.spec.ts file:

```
component.isBigButton = true;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

This isBigButton class works fine in the app, then I wanted to write unit tests for that, but I could not find isBigButton class

I wanted to use `.classList.contains('isBigButton'))` to test

isBigButton class inside :host of .scss file (my isBigButton class is written there)

```
:host {
  &.isBigButton {
    
  }
```

By using console.log I searched this isBigButton class inside `fixture.debugElement` and `fixture.nativeElement` => could not find isBigButton class.

**Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to wrap this component into a host component for this to work.

If the component is:

```
@Component({
  ....
  selector: 'my-component',
});
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() 
  @HostBinding('class.isBigButton') isBigButton = false;
}
```

Then in your test, create a `HostComponent` that houses `MyComponent`.

```
@Component({
  template: '<my-component [isBigButton]="isBigButton"></mycomponent>
})
class TestHostComponent {
  isBigButton: boolean;
}
```

Make sure you create `TestHostComponent` as the component to test.

You can do something like the following.

```
describe('MyComponent with greeter', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
  let component: TestHostComponent;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHostComponent, MyComponent]
    }).compileComponent();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should do xyz', () => {
    component.isBigButton = true;
    
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const isBigButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.isBigButton'));
    expect(isBigButton).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

  @Component({
    template: '<my-component [isBigButton]="isBigButton"></my-component>
  })
  class TestHostComponent {
    isBigButton: boolean;
  }
```

Comment: Everything works fine, thank you!!!